# SSH Protocol Mismatch error when accessing Rails server in Vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, puma

I am using vagrant. Here's the port forwarding rules of my Virtual box on which vagrant is up. [image]

Here's the vagrantfile.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "phacobox"

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
 # config.vm.box_url =

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2222

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # If true, then any SSH connections made will enable agent forwarding.
  # Default value: false
   config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
   config.vm.synced_folder "D:/Projects/VM/data", "/home/vagrant"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Don't boot with headless mode
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
  #   vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you're using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with CFEngine. CFEngine Community packages are
  # automatically installed. For example, configure the host as a
  # policy server and optionally a policy file to run:
  #
  # config.vm.provision "cfengine" do |cf|
  #   cf.am_policy_hub = true
  #   # cf.run_file = "motd.cf"
  # end
  #
  # You can also configure and bootstrap a client to an existing
  # policy server:
  #
  # config.vm.provision "cfengine" do |cf|
  #   cf.policy_server_address = "10.0.2.15"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with Puppet stand alone.  Puppet manifests
  # are contained in a directory path relative to this Vagrantfile.
  # You will need to create the manifests directory and a manifest in
  # the file default.pp in the manifests_path directory.
  #
  # config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
  #   puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
  #   puppet.manifest_file  = "default.pp"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with chef solo, specifying a cookbooks path, roles
  # path, and data_bags path (all relative to this Vagrantfile), and adding
  # some recipes and/or roles.
  #
  # config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
  #   chef.cookbooks_path = "../my-recipes/cookbooks"
  #   chef.roles_path = "../my-recipes/roles"
  #   chef.data_bags_path = "../my-recipes/data_bags"
  #   chef.add_recipe "mysql"
  #   chef.add_role "web"
  #
  #   # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
  #   chef.json = { mysql_password: "foo" }
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with chef server, specifying the chef server URL,
  # and the path to the validation key (relative to this Vagrantfile).
  #
  # The Opscode Platform uses HTTPS. Substitute your organization for
  # ORGNAME in the URL and validation key.
  #
  # If you have your own Chef Server, use the appropriate URL, which may be
  # HTTP instead of HTTPS depending on your configuration. Also change the
  # validation key to validation.pem.
  #
  # config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
  #   chef.chef_server_url = "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/ORGNAME"
  #   chef.validation_key_path = "ORGNAME-validator.pem"
  # end
  #
  # If you're using the Opscode platform, your validator client is
  # ORGNAME-validator, replacing ORGNAME with your organization name.
  #
  # If you have your own Chef Server, the default validation client name is
  # chef-validator, unless you changed the configuration.
  #
  #   chef.validation_client_name = "ORGNAME-validator"
end
```

And I am using Puma server. Here's it's config file.

```
   workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 2222
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/
  # deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I am using this to start the server-

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 2222
```

And this url to access it in host machine.

```
 http://127.0.0.1:2222/ , I have also tried localhost:2222
```

But it's showing this

[image]

Here's how my server looks like;-

[image]

I have seen a lot of links and tried alot of permutations and combinations but not able to access the server. Also, I have not been able to sync my host and vagrant folders.Please help.

EDIT 1: When I did shut down the VM, netstat -a doesn't show port 2222, so I think it's not occupied on my machine for some other task, but  rather this one only. So, there might be some other issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed `host` and `guest`

> ```
>   # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
>   # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
>   # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
>   # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
> ```

in your case you want to forward the port 2222 running on the guest to something on the host, you could just use the same port number to simplify things

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 2222, host: 2222
```

Comment: I have edited the guest port to 2222, but still same error

Comment: do you have something running on port 2222 on your host ? do you see the message when starting up your instance for `==> default: Forwarding ports...` ?

Comment: I just did netstat -a on my host....and it's showing 5-6 connections with 2222 port on my local address and 3-4 connections with 2222 port as foreign address. Few are established and few are time wait

Comment: so you should change your `host` port with a port number that is free

Comment: Should i change the port forwarding rules for VM also ?

Comment: when you change the `forwarded_port` from vagrantfile and reload the vm (`vagrant reload`) it update the rules for VM - whats the new error when you  forward guest 2222 on your host - It cannot be the same error about SSH (that was the error because of the port 22 forward which was SSH port) now you must have a new error

Comment: On assigning config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 2222, host: 2222 and using vagrant reload, it shows this error. * Forwarded port '2222' (host port) is declared multiple times with the protocol 'tcp'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114599/discussion-between-frederic-henri-and-jaydeep).

Comment: My network firewall, blocks this link. Is there any other option.

Comment: ok because you said you have connections already on port 2222 so change to use a port where nothing is listening , maybe 8080 or 8088 : `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 2222, host: 8088` and vagrant reload

Comment: After I did rebuild, It removed everything including rbenv and rails. I am doing it again but getting error while installing rbenv that '..libexec/rbenv' not found although it is there. So, I will get back to you after installing everything and testing your solution, if it resolves it.